# How to get Android application id?

Tags: android

In Android, how do I get the application's id programatically (or by some other method), and how can I communicate with other applications using that id?

Answer (score 193):

If your are looking for the value defined by `applicationId` in gradle, you can simply use

```
BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
```

EDIT 2022:

As indicated in the comments, `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID` is deprecated, but **for librairies only**. In this case, `BuildConfig.LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME` should be used instead, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42205767/context-getpackagename-vs-buildconfig-application-id?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top).

Also, now, `Context::getPackageName` returns the value defined by `applicationId` in gradle, even if you have several flavors with different `applicationId` (with a unique namespace), see [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set_the_application_id).

Comment: This would not be so useful if you are writing an Android Library

Comment: I use this to get applicationId in my Espresso test: private val targetContext = instrumentation.getTargetContext()
    private val applictionId = targetContext.getPackageName();

Comment: @SimonFeatherstone did you ever find out how to do it from a module?

Comment: @MihaiFischer you need to create a function to initialise the module/library and pass in that kind of information then.

Comment: This is now deprecated you should use `BuildConfig.LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42205767/context-getpackagename-vs-buildconfig-application-id?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top)

Answer (score 54):

If by `application id`, you're referring to `package name`, you can use the method `Context::getPackageName` ([http://http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName%28%29](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName%28%29)).

In case you wish to communicate with other application, there are multiple ways:

1. Start an activity of another application and send data in the "Extras" of the "Intent"
2. Send a broadcast with specific action/category and send data in the extras
3. If you just need to share structured data, use content provider
4. If the other application needs to continuously run in the background, use Server and "bind" yourself to the service.

If you can elaborate your exact requirement, the community will be able to help you better.

Comment: What if I want to show a list of apps, and need to have the id as an integer, just like all list-adapters need? I could use the install-time, but it's of a long type. Would casting it to int still help?

Comment: package name is not always applicationId, when you set it through build.gradle !

Comment: Actually, `Context.getPackageName()` _does_ return the application ID and _not_ the package name (although they are usually the same). The somewhat confusing name of the method is legacy. Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id

Comment: Context::getPackageName doesn't work if you use kotlin, it returns "function getPackageName (Kotlin reflection is not available)"

Comment: This is not must have your application id same as package name. This wont work if applicationID is set different to packageName.

Answer (score 7):

i'm not sure what "application id" you are referring to, but for a unique identifier of your application you can use:

getApplication().getPackageName() method from your current activity

Comment: each installed application have an unique id...is it possible to get an application's unique id from other application

Comment: Isn't it `getApplicationContext().getPackageName()`?

Comment: Suppose you have build types like a release or debug, and you have added a suffix, for example, "debug" to differentiate it from the main application, in that case getpackageName() will give you originalpackagename.debug

Answer (score 5):

For getting AppId (or package name, how some says), just call this:

But be sure that you importing `BuildConfig` with your app id packages path

```
BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
```

Answer (score 3):

Package name is your android app id .

String appId = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID

Or

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp

App Id  = com.whatsapp

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: [Open the Google Play Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Znc9I.png)

Step 2: Open any App in App Store
[Example: facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSO4L.png)

Step 3: Click on any App and Look at the Browser link and At the End **id=com.facebook.katana&hl=en** will be there and [this is your Apps Unique Id.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bncVs.png)

Answer (score 1):

Else you can get id of process your application runs in:

final static int android.os.Process.myPid() 
Returns the identifier of this process, which can be used with killProcess(int) and sendSignal(int, int).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you need the app/installation ID for, but you can review the existing possibilities in a great article from Android developers:

- http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

To sum up:

- `UUID.randomUUID()` for creating id on the first time an app runs after installation and simple retrieval afterwards
- `TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()` for actual device identifier
- `Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID` on relatively modern devices

Answer (score 0):

The `PackageInfo.sharedUserId` field will show the user Id *assigned in the manifest*.

If you want two applications to have the same userId, so they can see each other's data and run in the same process, then assign them the same userId in the manifest:

```
android:sharedUserId="string"
```

The two packages with the same sharedUserId need to have the same signature too.

I would also recommend reading [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#userid) for a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: 2 different application use the same package name means, the applications can share the data?...

Comment: No.  If two applications have the same shareUserId AND are signed with the same signature the can share data.  Package name is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the whole purpose is to communicate data with some other application, use Intent's sendBroadcast methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the new** Gradle build system then `getPackageName` will oddly return application Id, not package name. So MasterGaurav's answer is correct but he doesn't need to start off with ++

> If by application id, you're referring to package name...

See more about the differences [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename).

** not so new at this point

++ I realize that his answer made perfect sense in 2011

Answer (score 0):

Android App ES File Explorer shows the Android package name in the User Apps section which is useful for Bitwarden. Bitwarden refers to this as "android application package ID (or package name)".

Answer (score 0):

To track installations, you could for example use a UUID as an identifier, and simply create a new one the first time an app runs after installation. Here is a sketch of a class named “Installation” with one static method Installation.id(Context context). You could imagine writing more installation-specific data into the INSTALLATION file.

```
public class Installation {
private static String sID = null;
private static final String INSTALLATION = "INSTALLATION";
public synchronized static String id(Context context) {

    if (sID == null) {  
       File installation = new File(context.getFilesDir(), INSTALLATION);
       try {
           if (!installation.exists())
               writeInstallationFile(installation);
           sID = readInstallationFile(installation);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
    }
   return sID;
}

private static String readInstallationFile(File installation) throws IOException {
   RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(installation, "r");
   byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
   f.readFully(bytes);
   f.close();
   return new String(bytes);
}

private static void writeInstallationFile(File installation) throws IOException {
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(installation);
   String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
   out.write(id.getBytes());
   out.close();
}
```

}

Yon can see more at https://github.com/MShoaibAkram/Android-Unique-Application-ID

Answer (score 0):

This is now deprecated you should use `BuildConfig.LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42205767/context-getpackagename-vs-buildconfig-application-id?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top)

Comment: Please mention the alternative of BuildConfig