# Getting appid using package name

Tags: android

I use [market api](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) in order to gather information about applications from the market.

I use the following code in order to get the app id.

```
    public void getAppInfo() {

    AppsRequest appsRequest = AppsRequest.newBuilder()
            .setAppId("org.ajeje.locservice15")               
            .setWithExtendedInfo(true)
            .build();

   session.append(appsRequest, new Callback<AppsResponse>() {
   @Override
   public void onResult(ResponseContext context, AppsResponse response) {

   List<App> apps = response.getAppList(); 
   for (App app : apps) { 
        System.out.println("Title of the application is:"+app.getTitle());
        }
}
  });
   session.flush();
  }
```

Except for "com.example.android" for setAppId , the above code does not yield any response.

Is there an alternate method by which I could get the appid of an application when I have the package name for the application in the market?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: read answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264397/how-to-get-android-application-id

Comment: I am not talking about installed applications in the handset; but getting the app id using the api mentioned above by providing package name of the app as input.

Comment: Hey did you find any solution for that? I am facing same problem.

Comment: same here, me facing same problem?