# Get packageid from library before context is initialized

Tags: java, android, android-library

How can it get the packageid of the main application from one of its libraries. It is for a content provider string, which as I understand gets initialized before the context of the main application, so i cannot pass that to the library.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264397/how-to-get-android-application-id][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264397/how-to-get-android-application-id

Comment: @farhanlatheef
How can it help me, if i don't have any context yet? Since the content provider gets initialized before onCreate() in my application executes. Is there anything I have missed?