# Android application unique User ID installed on smartphone

Tags: android

How do I get list of android apps ID which were installed on smartphone?. All android application will have its unique ID. Is it possible to retrieve ID?

Comment: package name is the android unique id

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2695746/3144836

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Android application id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264397/how-to-get-android-application-id)

Answer (score 0):

Android unique app id is its package name

You can get the user installed apps like this:

```
List<PackageInfo> packList = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
for (int i=0; i < packList.size(); i++)
{
    PackageInfo packInfo = packList.get(i);
    if (  (packInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0)
    {
        String appName = packInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        Log.e("App № " + Integer.toString(i), appName);
    }
}
```

Or all the apps (including the system apps):

```
List<PackageInfo> packList = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
for (int i=0; i < packList.size(); i++)
{
    PackageInfo packInfo = packList.get(i);
    String appName = packInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
    Log.e("App № " + Integer.toString(i), appName);
}
```