# Context.getPackageName() vs BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID

Tags: android, gradle

I can retrieve the package name using:

```
Context.getPackageName()
```

or

```
BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
```

Is there any difference between those 2 ways?
Is one preferred to another in particular situations?
Is it safe to assume that they always give the same result?

Basically, **which one is better**?

Answer (score 39):

As of Android Studio 3.5, `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID` is deprecated and replaced with `BuildConfig.LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME`.

From [Android Google Source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/51644d6f302ea8c3616d98afde0b4ee30d7d4741):

> BuildConfig: Deprecate APPLICATION_ID in libraries.
>
> It is at best misleading, so it is marked as deprecated and replaced by
> LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME.

Comment: `in libraries` is very important in this sentence.

Comment: You saved me from chaos.

Answer (score 18):

`BuildConfig` is provided by `Gradle`. If you are not building using `Gradle` then you cannot access the package name using `BuildConfig`.

Using `Context` to get package name might not be applicable at times if there is no context or context is null, so you might then use `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID`.

I would use `Context.getPackageName()` because the result is provided from the operating system, rather than a constant in build parameters.

Answer (score 5):

`Context.getPackageName()` will return the application's package name you set in the manifest file as "package":

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.xxx"
...
```

`BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID` will return the the `BuildConfig` field value you set in your gradle file as "applicationId" :

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx"
```

Also, please note that `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID` is deprecated and is replaced with `BuildConfig.LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME`

Comment: In my case Context.getPackageName() returns the applicationId and not the packageName.

Comment: I used to be able to `import BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID` by preceding `BuildConfig` with my package name, but not in 2021. But I also cannot `import BuildConfig.LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME` by preceding `BuildConfig` with my package name.

Answer (score 2):

I used getPackageName() before - but only use BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID since it became available. Should be faster as it is only a variable and no call - but should not really matter. Also in libraries using getPackageName() might be still needed.

Answer (score 1):

It might possible to use both elements as basic measure against package tampering.
In your application you might insert some code like:

```
if (!BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.equals(getPackageName())) {
  insert code to report information about tampering to remote server
}
```

Sometime I get weird reports coming from some variant of my application that has been tampered by adding a prefix or suffix to the original packagename

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-native-config lib then go to the
`build.gradle` file and remove the development field data. It will run smoothly

```
productFlavors {
        theDev {
            applicationIdSuffix "" 
        }
        theProd {
            applicationIdSuffix "" 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both Context.getPackageName() and BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID are used to obtain the package

1. Context.getPackageName() is a method that can be called on any Context object like an Activity, Service, or Application and it returns the package name of the application as specified in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
2. BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID is automatically generated by the Android build system during the build process. It is derived from the applicationId property in the application's build.gradle file

   android {
   compileSdkVersion 32
   defaultConfig {
   applicationId "com.yourpackage.name"
   minSdkVersion 19
   targetSdkVersion 32
   versionCode 1
   ....

so in the end we can say that Context.getPackageName() is used to obtain the package name of the application at runtime while BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID is used to obtain the package name at compile time.

Comment: So, from your explanation if a developer is trying to get the name of the play store, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID is preferable because it is generated during compile time from build.gradle I guess. BTW, someone said it is deprecated , and a new way is BuildConfig.LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME.