# Ask user to allow all files access

Tags: android, kotlin

So, basically I need to ask the user for permission to access all files in android (**Yes, i know google won't allow it on the app store**). I've seen a bunch of tutorials like [this amazing one](https://commonsware.com/R/pages/chap-scoped-007.html) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65876736/how-do-you-request-manage-external-storage-permission-in-android) and all of them point to the same conclusion:

```
val uri = Uri.parse("package:${BuildConfig.LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME}")

    startActivity(
      Intent(
        Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION,
        uri
      )
    )
```

Obs: Had to change the "BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID" to "BuildConfig.LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME" as seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42205767/context-getpackagename-vs-buildconfig-application-id)

No matter how I try to implement this line of code in my app, nothing really happens, the screen that should ask for user permission doesn't show. Any clue on how to implement it?

Seems like every tutorial I see is outdated to the current version of android.

Comment: "Declare the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the manifest." - Have you done this as well?

Comment: Yep, pasted the "uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" " in the manifest

Comment: "Obs: Had to change the "BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID" to "BuildConfig.LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME" as seen in this post" -- that is only needed for libraries, and you can't do what you're trying to do for a library. You have to use the app's application ID.

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh, didn't knew that, when I try to use the APPLICATION_ID it request me to rename it, any clue where I find the app's application ID?

Comment: "when I try to use the APPLICATION_ID it request me to rename it" -- is your code in a library module? "any clue where I find the app's application ID?" -- if your code is in an app module, use `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID`. If your code is in a library module, I would have the app module supply the application ID via some API exposed by the library module.

Comment: @CommonsWare it's an app module, when I try "val uri = Uri.parse("package:${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}" it still require me to rename the variable.

Comment: I do not know what to tell you. In one of my projects, in the Jellyfish canary version of Android Studio, I have `private const val AUTHORITY = "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.provider"` in a viewmodel, and I am not getting any Lint errors or IDE inspection errors.

Comment: @CommonsWare I figured it out! In my Build.gradle there is "defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.qrcodekotlin"" , I just swapped the package:${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID} to package:com.example.qrcodekotlin and worked like a charm.