# How to find the App ID of android application

Tags: android, google-play-services, app-id

I'm learning android application. I've build simple app by the help of one's project . Now I want to upload in playstore for testing purpose, but I'm confused regarding following 2 terms : Startapp Developer and App ID

**strings.xml**

```
<!-- Change Startapp Developer and App ID -->
<string name="startapp_dev_id">102358176</string>
<string name="startapp_app_id">203718681</string>
```

[Screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsuzQ.jpg)

Where to find Startapp Developer and App ID ? I've found https://portal.startapp.com for App ID. Is this is associated with playstore or google account.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the `applicationId` of your Android app in your module's `build.gradle` file, as shown here:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    ...
}
```

See this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html) to learn more and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264397/how-to-get-android-application-id) for additional insights.

Comment: Yeah I'd seen this build.gradle, but how to find numerical ID such as "102358176", in build.gradle there is only text.